# Automatic reorder method list matlab

Tags: matlab, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Is there a way to automatically reorder all the methods in a matlab class in alphabetical order? If you go the Go To button in the editor, they are shown in alphabetical order. Is t possible to actually move the code so that the actual methods are in alphabetical order?

Thanks!